# match values from one file to other

Tags: bash, file, sed, awk, match

I was googling a lot but i have absolutely no idea how to do this:

I have 2 different files:

First in format:

```
name1 stuff stuff
name2 stuff stuff
name3 stuff stuff
name4 stuff stuff
```

Second in format:

```
name1 otherstuff
valueA otherstuff

name2 otherstuff
valueB otherstuff

name3 otherstuff
valueB otherstuff

name4 otherstuff
valueA otherstuff
```

What I need to do is to somehow split first file in 2, depending on value from second file, so the result will be something like:

fileWithValuesA:

```
name1 stuff stuff
name4 stuff stuff
```

fileWithValuesB:

```
name2 stuff stuff
name3 stuff stuff
```

The second file contains more info than first file, so I cannot check lines in 2 files simultaneously, because they won't be about the same name (that's the only think I thought of:()

Comment: i don't see any criteria for the splitting, so based on this, second file is useless. Is it a patterne matching, specific predefine vaue (how to know them) ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the file2 structure is exactly as you mentioned throughout the file:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a=""} (NF){if (a=="")a=$1; else {print a " " $1; a=""}}' file2 > file_temp

$ grep -f <(awk '/valueA$/{print $1}' file_temp) file1 > fileWithValuesA; cat fileWithValuesA
name1 stuff stuff
name4 stuff stuff

$ grep -f <(awk '/valueB$/{print $1}' file_temp) file1 > fileWithValuesB; cat fileWithValuesB
name2 stuff stuff
name3 stuff stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

For something that is sufficiently specialized, I would just break out the `Python`, since it is more readable and more maintainable for similar such tasks.

In the code below, I assume that `FileA` is your first file and `FileB` is your second file.
It is not hard to make them into command line options.

```
refFile = open('FileB')
fileToSplit = open('FileA')

# Read the reference file and remove blank lines
temp = refFile.read().split("\n")
temp = [x for x in temp if x != ""]

# Build a map based on refFile
mymap = {}
for i in xrange(0, len(temp), 2):
   mymap[temp[i].split()[0]] = temp[i+1].split()[0]

# Open two output files and  make a pass through fileToSplit
OutValA = open("fileWithValuesA","w")
OutValB = open("fileWithValuesB","w")

for line in fileToSplit:
  if mymap[line.split()[0]] == "valueA":
    OutValA.write(line)
  else:
    OutValB.write(line)

OutValA.close()
OutValB.close()
refFile.close()
fileToSplit.close()
```

Comment: +1... I was just about to provide another `awk` based solution, but realized that it would follow almost same algorithm as this. Only plus point would have been, the filenames need not be hard-coded.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `valueA` or `valueB` are dynamic values, so they shouldn't be the key words directly.

#### Here is the solution to put into one awk. It easily generate many different value files, if there are more than 2 value keys.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print a[$1]> "fileWith" $3}' file1 RS="" file2
```

after run the awk command, you will get several files, all files named by the value[AB...].

```
$ cat fileWithvalueA
name1 stuff stuff
name4 stuff stuff

$ cat fileWithvalueB
name2 stuff stuff
name3 stuff stuff
```